# Background Color for second div won't show up

Tags: html, css

I am new to css and html but know basics.  I am trying to create a page where the background is different for different divs.  For example the Top portion of the page is one div where I have info and buttons and the bottom part of the page is gonna have license information like a real website might have for example "contact me".

My problem is the background-color for the upper div is showing, but the background for the lower div is not showing up.  I have been trouble shooting for a while now and no answers on here seem to apply to my issue.

Here is my code: 
HTML:

```
<!DOCType HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "Topper">
            <div style = "height: 500px;width: 800px">
                <h1><b>Lets Play a Game</b></h1>
                <p>blah blah blah</p>
                <a href="SecondPage.html">
                    <img src="PlayButton.png" alt="Photoshopped Button for later" style="width:190px;height:135px;"">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id= "Footer">
            <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 100px;">
                <p>This is a test for Location</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#Topper {
 background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

p {
    width: 500px;
    border-style: hidden;
    text-align: justify;
    word-break: keep-all;
}
#Footer {
    background-color: green;
}
```

I suspect the issue lies in the length and width of the background but I am not sure what to do I feel I have tried everything.  Even when I tried to make the background the entire page 800 by 800 it still didn't show.

Ps. I dont know how to show you what the page actually looks like but the top of the page is grey and the bottom part is just white without  the green background.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why  you created it so complex you can get by `flex` quite easily.

Comment: I updated my answer and posted 2nd option to get same layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add following css  and remove inline css and also take care of `<a href="SecondPage.html">` inline css in last you used `""`.

```
#Footer {
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  width: 100%;  /* Added */
}
```

```css
#Topper {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

p {
  width: 500px;
  border-style: hidden;
  text-align: justify;
  word-break: keep-all;
}

#Footer {
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  width: 100%;  /* Added */
}
```

```html
<div id="Topper">
  <div style="height: 500px;width: 800px">
    <h1><b>Lets Play a Game</b></h1>
    <p>blah blah blah</p>
    <a href="SecondPage.html">
      <img src="PlayButton.png" alt="Photoshopped Button for later" style="width:190px;height:135px;">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="Footer">
  <div>
    <p>This is a test for Location</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Second way to get it by using `flex`.

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#Topper {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height:calc(100vh - 70px);  /* 70px is your footer height */
}

#Topper>div {
  flex: 1;
}

#Footer>div {
  flex: 1;
}

p {
  width: 500px;
  border-style: hidden;
  text-align: justify;
  word-break: keep-all;
}

#Footer {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="Topper">
  <div>
    <h1><b>Lets Play a Game</b></h1>
    <p>blah blah blah</p>
    <a href="SecondPage.html">
      <img src="PlayButton.png" alt="Photoshopped Button for later" style="width:190px;height:135px;">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="Footer">
  <div>
    <p>This is a test for Location</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But can you explain why it didn't work for the second one?  It worked for the first div in the same way I did for the second one but now that I only changed the bottom one and they both work why is that?

Comment: When you used `position` the div come out  from flow so it will not take width of it's parent div. so i assigned width to position div.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to be add the `div` element after `#Footer` id selector.
( `#` is id selector in CSS files 
[class and id selector in css](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/classid/))

however you make this is absolute.

there is some relation for position property of relative and absolute.

```
#Footer div {
    background-color: green;
}
```